# How can i convert 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023' into '2023-01-25 00:10:28.000' in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, datetime

How can I convert 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023' into '2023-01-25 00:10:28.000' format in SQL Server? KST means korea standard time. I need to remove that.

I have tried this and it failed:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 
        CAST(SUBSTRING('Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023', PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%', 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023'), 4) AS INT) AS [year],
        CAST(DATEPART(MONTH, SUBSTRING('Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023', PATINDEX('%[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]%', 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023'), 3)) AS INT) AS [month],
        CAST(SUBSTRING('Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023', PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]%', 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023'), 2) AS INT) AS [day],
        CAST(SUBSTRING('Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023', PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]:%', 'Wed Jan 25 00:10:28 KST 2023'), 8) AS TIME) AS [time]
)
SELECT 
    CONVERT(DATETIME, CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [year]) + '-' + 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [month]) + '-' + 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [day]) + ' ' + 
    CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [time]), 120)
FROM
    cte
```

Comment: You should ***ALWAYS*** define an explicit **length** when using `VARCHAR` or `NVARCHAR` in SQL Server. Otherwise, the code might fall back to a **default length** of ***1*** character.....

Comment: CONVERT CC https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16